# prefix/postfix route with database value

Tags: routing

In the magento admin area there is a random key generated which is required as part of the route. I would like to recreate this with a value that is held in my database. But I don't know where to start.

I have looked online but cant find anything covering this subject and I cant find where and how the code is generated in the core.

what i currently have is

`http://myStore.local/index.php/prefs/index/edit/id/174`

What i'd like

`http://myStore.local/index.php/prefs/index/edit/id/174/someKeyFromTheDatabase`

How do I recreate this type of route?

Answer (score 2):

That value is generated from the names of the module, controller and action and a form_key that is different from session to session.
You can get the correct url like this:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('prefs/index/edit', array('id'=>174));
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to add a new value to the url:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('prefs/index/edit', array('id'=>174)).'value_here';
```

If you want that value to have a name also then do this:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('prefs/index/edit', array('id'=>174, 'value_name'=>'value_here'));
```

Comment: would it be possible to set a value in the database then add that value on to the end on of my url? the way I read `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('prefs/index/edit', array('id'=>174));` that is the same as my first example, or have I got it wrong

Comment: @tony09uk Ok. Maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you want to **replace** the key value, or you just want to **add** a new value to the url?

Comment: I would like to add an additional value from the database to the end of the URL.

Comment: @tony09uk. I've edited the answer. If you think I still misunderstood just ignore me and I will shut up.

Comment: thanks for your help, your edit seems to be what I want, Now I will have to go away and work out how to apply that as I have only ever worked with module/controller/method/param add more after paramaters after the /param is something I cant get my head around at the moment

Comment: @tony09uk did you ever finish this?